# What does "carved in relief" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I was looking up “cameo” and came across this definition:

> A gem or shell carved in relief, especially one in which the raised design and the background consist of layers of contrasting colors.
> <sub>Source: [American Heritage Dictionary definition of “cameo”](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cameo#C5050300)</sub>

This just confuses me more. What does “carved in relief” mean?

Comment: I think it is bas-relief.

Comment: @LucianSava There are both bas-relief and haut-relief (low relief and high relief). Cameo in the strict sense is almost always high relief.

Comment: @StoneyB, yes, you’re right, cameo is actually what the OP is looking for. I’m familiar from my language with the term BASORELIEF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Carved in relief" is a style of carving where an image stands out (or occasionally is cut into) a flat background.

For example this is a relief carving of a Viking ship:

[image: low relief carving of Viking ship]

Cameo jewellery typically also displays this kind of carving:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Did you try looking up *relief* in a dictionary? Check out Macmillan, definition #4:

> **[relief](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/relief)** (*n.*) `art` a design or sculpture consisting of a raised surface on a flat background

You can also see some examples by looking up the phrase on [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1204&bih=827&q=%22carved%20in%20relief%22&oq=%22carved%20in%20relief%22).

The woman on the brooch on the left is *carved* in relief. On the other hand, the wheel on the right is *stamped* in relief:

[image]         [image]

In addition to being used in the phrase *in relief*, the word *relief* can also be used adjectivally:

> *Everything that does not exist is a relief sculpture carved into the stone of consciousness*.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the background has been cut away to make it look like the the sculpted or carved material has been raised.